# Laravel authentication problem with multiple guards

Tags: laravel, authentication

im new to laravel and im trying to create login function with multiple guards. However when i insert the correct credentials in the form, it does not authenticate properly. I cant seem to find the problem with my login controller, any ideas?

This is my AdminLoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // validate the form data

        $this->validate($request, [
            'admin_email ' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

        //attempt to log the user in
        if( Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['admin_email'=>$request->admin_email, 'admin_password'=>$request->admin_password], $request->remember))
        {
            //if successful then send to their location
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');

        }



        //if fail redirect back to the login with the data
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('admin_email','remember'));


    }
}
```

This one is my form

```
   @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Admin-Login') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login.submit') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Email Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="admin_email" type="email" class="form-control @error('admin_email') is-invalid @enderror" name="admin_email" value="{{ old('admin_email') }}" required autocomplete="admin_email" autofocus>

                                    @error('admin_email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="admin_password" type="password" class="form-control @error('admin_password') is-invalid @enderror" name="admin_password" required autocomplete="current-admin_password">

                                    @error('admin_password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                            {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Login') }}
                                    </button>

                                    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                            {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

This one is the Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'admin_email',
        'admin_password',

    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'admin_password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Edited: This is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminLoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminLoginController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\adminController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

my dd($request)

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#43 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#260 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#268 ▶}
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#44 ▶}
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#51 ▶}
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#47 ▶}
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#48 ▶}
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#46 ▶}
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/admin/login"
  #requestUri: "/admin/login"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Illuminate\Session\Store {#300 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  -isSafeContentPreferred: null
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

This is my config/auth file

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'resident' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'residents',
        ],
    ],

  'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        'residents' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Resident::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'residents' => [
            'provider' => 'residents',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Can you show routes and elaborate what " it does not authenticate properly " means? Any errors etc?

Comment: Also in your form the email input is named "email" but in validation you try to validate "admin_email". Perhaps `dd($request)` before your validation and check.

Comment: Take a look at [point 3 in this article](https://ralphjsmit.com/laravel-validation), I feel like validation is not correct in your case.

Comment: @geertjanknapen hi thankyou for replying i added route in my post. What I meant by "does not authenticate properly" is that i already have the user's credential stored in my database. However, when i try to use the credential to login, it does not log in the user. (It does not redirect to admin.dashboard as shown in AdminLoginController.)

Comment: Can you `dd()` the request and add that aswell.

Comment: @geertjanknapen i changed the input name in my form to match the validation (admin_email and admin_password), still no luck :(

Comment: So everywhere it's changed to `admin_email` and `admin_password`? Perhaps update code in question to latest version.

Comment: @geertjanknapen code is updated sir

Comment: change `$request->email` into `$request->admin_email` (same for password) in this line: `if( Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['admin_email'=>$request->email, 'admin_password'=>$request->password]`

Comment: done sir, however still cant authenticate properly. there's a message on the admin_email ('property accessed via magic method'). What does this indicate?

Comment: Interesting read about magic methods [here](https://dev.to/nvio/laravel-greatest-trick-revealed-magic-methods-31om), however they should not stop you from being able to login.. any actual errors?

Comment: @geertjanknapen no errors showing, however after i click the submit button it just did a refresh and wont redirect to the intended page :(

Comment: do you use `hash` or `bcrypt` when registering your user?
do you see hashed phrases in your `admins` table?

Comment: yes i did, i use the Hash::make ('password') command when inserting user into the table.( using comand line) . The password in the table also appear in hashed

Comment: and what does `Auth::guard('admin')` exactly do?

Comment: @PouyaParsaei It defines which models to look for when the login button is pressed

Comment: @ERENYEETGAR Have you set up `config/auth.php` properly?

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes, i updated my post with the config/auth.php file

Comment: @ERENYEETGAR Take a look at [this article](https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-8-login-with-custom-guard-example#:~:text=Laravel%20uses%20web%20as%20default,create%20login%20system%20using%20guard.).